# how to handle spring wrapped hibernate exception?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

spring template will wrap hibernate exceptions into `DataAccessExceptions`.  so trying to directly capture hibernate exceptions won't work. like this

```
try{
    springdao.update(row)
}
catch(HibernateException e) {
    //won't do 
}
```

questions:

1. what's the best practice to capture DataAccessException wrapped hibernate exception ? just `catch(DataAccessException)` ?
2. even though spring has wrapped that exception, when it is thrown. it exhibits as just original hibernate exception. like below, why ?

> Could not synchronize database state with session 
>   org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by
>   another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its better to handle `DataAccessException` instead of `HibernateException` or `SQLException`. Because it describes the issue in more generalized way. In case if you change your ORM/ Database later, it will handle your database related exception handling in same manner. And also it contains the same exception as that of Hibernate. Even in case of Non-SQL databases, same exception is thrown

Spring documentation says:

> This exception hierarchy aims to let user code find and handle the
>   kind of error encountered without knowing the details of the
>   particular data access API in use (e.g. JDBC). Thus it is possible to
>   react to an optimistic locking failure without knowing that JDBC is
>   being used.

Comment: but what if you want to distinguish between different exceptions, say connection exception and stale object exception. also for question 2, why it still display as original hibernate exception in log. ?

Comment: check complete exception hierarchy : http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html
http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/dao/NonTransientDataAccessException.html

Comment: @zinking As I already said that DataAccessException is a more generalized form of exceptions thrown by many different JPA apis. So its just a kind of categorization that how different kind of exceptions thrown by different ORM/JPA apis will be mapped into one generalized form, but containing different data/msg thrown by actual originator. In case later you want to change your database/ORM technology, you don't need to change your already existing exception hierarchy.